# Can't use DBMS_RANDOM functions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I use Oracle Database 11g and I have a fairly simple code:

```
set serveroutput on format wrapped;
declare
result_ clob;
begin
result_ := dbms_random.string('P', 10);
dbms_output.put_line(result_);
end;
```

When I try to run it gives me an error saying:

```
identifier 'DBMS_RANDOM' must be declared
```

Why **dbms_random** is not recognized as a valid identifier? Do I have to import it?

Comment: it is dbms_random, not dmbs_random. And you should get a grant from a DBA if you do not have rights to use it.

Comment: As @FlorinGhita said. If you have the sys password, this is how to grant (execute as sys): `GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_RANDOM TO <your user name here>;`

Comment: @FlorinGhita sorry, it was a typo. I edited the question. But the problem still persists.

Comment: @FlorinGhita Thanks for quick help. It was a privilege issue as you mentioned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably this is a permissions problem. [EXECUTE on DBMS_RANDOM is not granted by default](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_random.htm#ARPLS67490), so you need a DBA user to grant you the EXECUTE privilege.

```
grant execute on dbms_random to << your_username >>;
```

There is an outside chance the package is not installed, although installation is the default. Again, you need a DBA user to check, and if need be run the installation script.

Comment: I didn't have a permission to use dbms_random. I could run the code successfully once I gained permission.